# why is this array to 2d array boolean true?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, boolean

Hi I happen to come across a code that my friend sent me, and am having trouble making out the second part of the print statement.. `a[3]` is 4, which is in row 0 column 2 (`b[0][2]`), but why is `a[2]` which is 53, proving true to `b[2][1] == 43` ???  (The code prints 'true true' btw.)

```
class Ex1{
     public static void main(String[] args) {

         int a[] = { 1,2,053,4};
         int b[][] = { {1,2,4} , {2,2,1},{0,43,2}};

         System.out.print(a[3]==b[0][2] );
         System.out.print(" " + (a[2]==b[2][1]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because `053` is an octal number equal to `43` in decimal.

The `0` prefix denotes an octal value in Java and some other languages (Perl, Ruby, C and derived, Javascript to name a few).

Comment: oh.. so its like binary/hexadecimal stuff. thanks now im pretty clear on it :)

Answer (score 3):

Numbers starting with `0` are octal in Java.

And in your case `43` decimal is equal to `053` octal.

Answer (score 3):

In Java and several other languages, an integer literal beginning with `0` is interpreted as an octal (`base 8`) quantity. Here `053` is an octal number, which is value of `43` in `base 10`.

[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) says

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java octal numbers start with 0. So octal 53 equals decimal 43.